# Can't cast ServiceClient to WSBindingProvider

Tags: java

So I have this web service(based on axis2) which is supposed to act as a client to other web service. But when trying to cast my servicePort (docManClient) to WSBindingProvider I get ClassCastException error:

com.sun.proxy.$Proxy283 cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider

What confuses me is that this code works ok when execution from simple java application, but when execution from web service it fails. Also I've noticed that when executed from simple java application docManClient is a SEIStub object but when this code is executed inside my axis2 webservice, docManClient is JAXWSProxyHandler. I don't know if that helps or what should I do.

How can I fix or analyse deeply this classcast exception? Is there a way to avoid casting it to WSBindingProvider and set headers with JAXWSProxyHandler?

Thanks in advance.

```
DocumentManagement_Service docManService = new DocumentManagement_Service();
DocumentManagement docManClient = docManService.getBasicHttpBindingDocumentManagement();
DocumentManagement docManClientP = docManService.getBasicHttpBindingDocumentManagement(null);

try
{
// The namespace of the OTAuthentication object
final String ECM_API_NAMESPACE = "urn:api.ecm.opentext.com";


// Create a SOAP header
SOAPHeader header = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();

// Add the OTAuthentication SOAP header element
SOAPHeaderElement otAuthElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName(ECM_API_NAMESPACE, "OTAuthentication"));

// Add the AuthenticationToken SOAP element
SOAPElement authTokenElement = otAuthElement.addChildElement(new QName(ECM_API_NAMESPACE, "AuthenticationToken"));
authTokenElement.addTextNode(authToken);

// Set the SOAP header on the docManClient

//Object pt = docManService.getPort(do);

//ServiceClient sc = docManService.getServiceClient(docManService.getServiceName())

//BindingProvider bp =  ((BindingProvider) docManClient);

((WSBindingProvider) docManClient).setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(otAuthElement));

...
```

DocumentManagement:

```
       /**


* This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.


* JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035


* Generated source version: 2.2


* 


*/
"urn:xxxx")
@XmlSeeAlso({
com.opentext.ecm.api.ObjectFactory.class,
com.opentext.livelink.service.core.ObjectFactory.class,
com.opentext.livelink.service.docman.ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface DocumentManagement {


/**
 * 
 * @param nodeID
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "RemoveFavorite", action = "urn:xxxx/RemoveFavorite")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "RemoveFavorite", targetNamespace = "urn:xxx", className = "xxxx.RemoveFavorite")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "RemoveFavoriteResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:xxxx", className = "xxxx.RemoveFavoriteResponse")
public void removeFavorite(
    @WebParam(name = "nodeID", targetNamespace = "urn:xxxx")
    long nodeID);
```

DocumentManagement_Service:

```
    /**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
* JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
*/
@WebServiceClient(name = "DocumentManagement", targetNamespace = "urn:xxx", wsdlLocation = "xxxx")
public class DocumentManagement_Service
extends Service



{

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("xxxx");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    DOCUMENTMANAGEMENT_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    DOCUMENTMANAGEMENT_EXCEPTION = e;
}
```

Comment: I try to change WSBindingProvider to BindingProvider but always failed , Error : "username/password Not valid
"

Comment: After generate classes from .wsdl file youo should get service class which extends ```javax.xml.ws.Service``` and interface ```...PortType``` inside you have method correnspondig to operations from wsdl. This interface you could cast to ```javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider```

Comment: Sorry i dont understand u, i try yhis :  `Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY", Collections.singletonList("pass"));
    headers.put("BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY", Collections.singletonList("user"));  bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);`

Comment: show how looks like classes `DocumentManagement_Service` and `DocumentManagement`

Comment: now @Victor1125